# How do I use docker from local to a remote machine?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I've noticed that boot2docker runs docker on a VM as a deamon on port 2375.
Then I use local Mac OS X 'docker' command and it executes all calls on VM.

These are the commands I use:

```
boot2docker start
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://:2375
```

And then 'docker images' (for example) is running on VM.

How can I do the same with a physical machine rather then VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boot2docker is meant to be for dev purpose. It will spawn a VM. For bare metal, simply install docker on the host and start the docker daemon with `docker -d -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243`.
WARNING: This is very dangerous. Anyone will have root access to your host. In order to secure this, you should change `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` and either use a SSH tunnel or a nginx/apache frontend with authentification.

On you mac, then just `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<host ip>:4243`

Comment: Just to add to this answer, boot2docker also uses certificates to connect to the host. While it is still open, its a little more secure.